# Can I use axios interceptors to replace an API request with local storage data?

Tags: javascript, axios, local-storage, interceptor

I have an api client in my application with some interceptors:

```
const api = new OpenAPIClientAxios({...})
const client = api.initSync()
client.interceptors.request.use(...)
client.interceptors.response.use(...)
```

I want to write a request interceptor that will check for some data in local storage.  If the data is present, I would like to *not make a request at all*, rather, simply respond with the local storage data.

Is this possible?  Or am I misusing interceptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptors can only be used to manipulate the configuration of requests and responses. Unfortunately, you cannot bypass a request entirely with them.

Axios does provide an `adapter` config which...

> allows custom handling of requests

Using this, you can create an Axios instance with a custom `adapter` to intercept requests and provide responses using local data.

```js
// mock localStorage
const localStorage = {s:{},setItem(k,v){this.s[k]=v},getItem(k){return this.s[k]??null}};
// mock OpenAPI client
const client = /* api.initSync() */ axios.create({ baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" });

const wrapper = axios.create({
  adapter: ({ adapter, ...config }) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    if (data) {
      // return a valid response
      return Promise.resolve({
        data,
        config,
        status: 200,
      });
    }
    
    // otherwise pass-through to the real client
    return client(config);
  }
});

(async () => {
  // with no data present
  console.log("no local data:", (await wrapper.get("/todos/1")).data);

  // with local data
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify({ foo: "FOO" }));
  console.log("with local data:", (await wrapper.get("/todos/1")).data);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.6.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can this be used on an axios client created via open api client axios' initSync method?

Comment: Also, you think the adapter fn can return either a Promise or a client?

Comment: @AaronParisi 1) yes, as long as the client is actually an Axios instance. 2) It's not returning `client`, it's returning a call to `client()` which returns a promise

Comment: makes sense - I'm getting a loop of infinite requests in my browser but will mess with it, I think your answer is on the right track

Comment: @AaronParisi make sure you're using `{ adapter, ...config }` in the `adapter` function parameter. You want to extract the `adapter` from the passthrough request

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose another approach: instead of adding an interceptor to axios, you could write a function that abstract the retrieval of the data and that would:

- Check the local data and return the found data if any
- Execute the remote call otherwise

In other words, write a domain service / repository.